Get full Excel address synced to OneDrive ThisWorkbook.FullName
I currently use this solution via VBA:
Function CaminhoLocal() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim caminho As String
    Dim Path As String

    Path = ThisWorkbook.Path

    If Path Like "https://*" Then
        Path = Replace(Path, "https://", "")
        Path = Replace(Path, "/", "\")

        For i = 1 To Len(Path)
            If Mid(Path, i, 1) = "\" Then
                caminho = Environ("OneDrive") & "\" & Mid(Path, i + 1)

                If Dir(caminho, vbDirectory) <> "" Then
                    CaminhoLocal = caminho & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Else
        CaminhoLocal = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    End If
End Function



Sub TesteCaminhoLocal()

MsgBox (CaminhoLocal)

End Sub

credits to: @Robert here on stackoverflow
I am using this option since the function created by
guwidoe named GetLocalOneDrivePath which is on github stopped working for me, does anyone else use this solution or have any other suggestions besides the ones below?
crash, not works for me:
https://gist.github.com/guwidoe/038398b6be1b16c458365716a921814d
adds bars that do not exist in the Excel address:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-technet-forums/1331519b-1dd1-4aa0-8f4f-0453e1647f57
